# Wanted: an alternative to "COPY to/from ... " for Pl/pgSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

The following code:

```
Copy ( select bla
         from some_table p,
              some_procedure (par1 := null,
                              par2 := null ) as sp
        where p.var1 = sp.var1
        order 
           by some_table_id) to stdout;
```

... works inside a script (i.e. with psql) but it fails inside a  Pl/pgSQL function.

The error message, when inside a function, is the following:

```
"ERROR:  cannot COPY to/from client in PL/pgSQL"
```

My question is: 
How can I do the same thing inside the Pl/pgSQL function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stdout` from the view point of a function would simply be the client running the statement.

So just declare your function as `returns table()` and return the result of the query:

```
create function get_data(var1 ..., var2 ...) 
  returns table (bla....)
as
$$
  select bla
  from some_table p
   join some_procedure (par1 := null, par2 := null ) as sp
      on p.var1 = sp.var1
   order by some_table_id;
$$
language sql;
```

---

If that is an anonymous PL/pgSQL block, you can iterate over the result and then "print" it using `raise notice`:

```
do
$$
declare 
  l_row record;
begin
  for l_row in (select bla
                from some_table p
                  join some_procedure (par1 := null, par2 := null ) as sp
                    on p.var1 = sp.var1
                  order by some_table_id) loop 
     raise notice '%s', l_row::text;
  end loop;
end;
$$
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ... one thing I should have specified in more detail is that the PL/pgSQL function I mentioned is an anonymous function ... I guess in this case I need to use: "perform bla from some_table p ..." , correct?

Comment: @Thomas_SO: well, for an anonymous function a remotely similar thing would be to iterate over the result and "print" the values using `raise notice`